# Cast int variable to double

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I am a beginner C# programmer, and I am trying to create a calculator. I can't seem to figure out how to cast an `int` variable to a `double`. This is what I have so far:

```
public void oImpartire() {
    if (rezultat % value == 0)
    {
        rezultat /= value;
    }
    else {
       (double)rezultat /= value;  // this should be double but I get an error
    }
}
```

How can I make this work?

EDIT: Both `result` and `value` are `int` variables.

Comment: **Read the error message.**

Comment: Why converting int to double any way? Integer does not have any decimals. Anyway, you can use double.Parse() method.

Comment: @Mitja no you can't; `double.Parse` works with *strings* only.

Comment: We do not know the types of `rezultat` and `value` because you did not include the code segment in which they are declared. Such information is important when asking a question which involves casting.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't find that an obvious assumption considering the question.

Comment: @H2CO3: codesparkle is not the OP.

Comment: @Rotem yes, of course... you're technically correct, and it's a good advice for the OP... But still, it *is* pretty obvious in this particular case.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know. The link is an expression of agreement.

Comment: @H2CO3 Let's say we're both right and not pollute the comments area :)

Comment: What calculation do you want this code to perform. That's not clear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(double)rezultat /= ...
```

is not good. The result of a casting expression is always an rvalue, i. e. something that cannot be assigned to. Related: you can't change the type of an expression (you can cast it, but that won't really change its type, just act as another type temporarily). Once you declared your variable as, say, an `int`, you won't be able to store a double in it - however you cast the division, etc. it will always be truncated in the end.

You most likely have to introduce a `double` temporary variable to store the result of the division.

Comment: As a side note, if the OP is developing a calculator application, he is much better off using the `decimal` type rather than a `double`.

Comment: @Rotem yes. I still don't see why he needs to perform modulo on doubles, though..

Answer (score 26):

```
   Convert.ToDouble(int);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble.aspx

Comment: yes but will not actualy convert my variable to a double variable it will convert the value isen't that righT?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @user985482 you can not convert the type of a variable. C# is statically typed.

Answer (score 2):

If both of your variables are not `double`s, assign them into a `double` variable and then divide.

```
VarDouble = (double)int.....; VarDouble /= VarDouble1 etc

(double)rezultat /= value
```

I presume you are trying to make `rezultat` a `double` and I presume it's not declared as one and you just can't do that. Your resulting variable that will hold the `result` must also be a `double` or you will just get a whole number not rounded.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of the `rezultat` variable. If it's `double`, then you don't have to do anything, integer division won't be used in any case. But if it's `int`, then your cast doesn't make any sense, you can't store a `double` value in an `int` variable.

So, the correct solution depends on what exactly do you want to do. But if your goal is to have the result of the actual division as a `double`, you will need some `double` variable for that. And if you have that, your `if` won't make any sense anymore, just use `double` division in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double rezultat = 1992;
rezultat /= value;
```

`resultat` must be a `double` to store the result of `rezultat / value`. Otherwise, if both `resultat` and `value` are `int`, you won't get floating point numbers. For example, `5 / 3 = 1`, but `(double)5 / 3 = 1.666667`. Notice that the value `1.6666667` is just a `double`.